# Google Cloud ML submit job error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-sdk

I am unable to submit jobs to Google Cloud ML Engine.

I can run my training job locally with the command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train ` 
    --package-path "./content_extraction" `
    --module-name "content_extraction.task" `
    --
```

but when I try to submit the job to Cloud ML with the following command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "content-extraction-v1" `
    --staging-bucket "gs://sl-content-extraction-v1-staging/" `
    --job-dir "gs://sl-contentextraction-traininglogs/v1" `
    --package-path "./content_extraction" `
    --module-name "content_extraction.task" `
    --region "EUROPE-WEST3" `
    --
```

I get the following error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process:
>   u'c:\users\stewar~1\appdata\local\temp\tmp1ptz4f\output\content_extraction-0.0.0.tar.gz'
>   while another exception was active  [Could not copy
>   [c:\users\stewar~1\appdata\local\temp\tmp1ptz4f\output\content_extraction-0.0.0.tar.gz]
>   to
>   [content-extraction-v1/d07e4aad8f28eb0207f548198f74de5925902bcb7761f54216978d4ea808e24f/content_extraction-0.0.0.tar.gz].
>   Please retry: HTTPError 404: Not Found]

The specific temp file changes every time i try to run the command but always with the same error. After running the command that temp file exists and I can access it manually on the file system without encountering any locks

Any idea how I get past this?

Comment: Do you mind mentioning what directory you are in when you run the command?

Comment: I am in the parent directory of the package

Comment: I've brought this to the attention of someone I think can help, but they are currently out of the office for a few days. We'll get back to you as soon as we can. We apologize for the inconvenience. In the meantime, you can manually create the .tgz by creating a blank `__init__.py` file in the package directory and a `setup.py` in the directory you are in.  See https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer#adding_standard_pypi_dependencies

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help. I'm manually uploading the package for now so got a workaround but would be good to get to the bottom of it